# Augmenting a class that is also a namespace from a separate file in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to augment a class with an additional field from a separate file. However, I'm having trouble because this seems to make the namespace for nested declarations inaccessible.

Augment.ts:

```
declare module './MyClass' {
  export default interface MyClass {
    augmentedField: any
  }
}
import MyClass from './MyClass';
export { MyClass };
```

MyClass.ts:

```
namespace MyClass {
  interface Nested {
  }
}
class MyClass {}
export default MyClass;
```

User.ts:

```
import {MyClass} from './Augment'
interface Example {
  nested: MyClass.Nested
}
```

Fails with:

> 'MyClass' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

Any idea how we can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that augmenting a default export isn't supposed to be supported at all, but the interface case currently slips past that check and causes other buggy behavior.  I filed [a TypeScript bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27286).  Your best option is probably to make `MyClass` a named export of `MyClass.ts` rather than a default export.